# Woocommerce show tax amount with 2 decimals, while everything else with 0

Tags: woocommerce, decimal, price

I have a function that shows tax (MVA) in the email sent to the customer.

```
// Add total taxes as a separated line before order total on orders and emails
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'insert_custom_line_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
function insert_custom_line_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    // Display only the gran total amount
    $gran_total = (float) $order->get_total();
    $total_rows['order_total']['value'] = is_wc_endpoint_url() ? $total_html : strip_tags( $total_html );

    // Custom tax calculation (for 25% tax rate)
    $total_tax_amount = wc_price(  $gran_total - $gran_total / 1.25 );
    $total_tax_amount = is_wc_endpoint_url() ? $total_tax_amount : strip_tags( $total_tax_amount );

    // Create a new row for total tax
    $tax_row = array( 'order_tax_total' => array(
        'label' => __('MVA:','woocommerce'),
        'value' => $total_tax_amount,
    ) );

    $total_rows['order_total']['value'] = wc_price( $gran_total );

    return $total_rows + $tax_row;
}
```

The global setting for decimals in WC is 0 decimals. So all prices are shown like 399kr.
The function above shows tax as a whole number, but I want it to be displayed with 2 decimals like 58,99kr.

How can I achieve that without changing the global decimal setting from 0 to 2?

I tried round () and 'decimals' => 2, but it didn't affect the outcome